# Do MVC frameworks vary greatly from one language to another ie ASP.NET, Python, RoR, etc

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am used to the ASP.NET MVC framework but was wondering if anyone had any good literature on a comparison of MVC frameworks.

Is one better than another?

Has anyone worked with multiple ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is one better than another? That is a giant and mostly subjective can of worms. Most MVC frameworks will have a lot in common.

Are there differences? Yes. Here are some of the considerations that people seem to care about:

1) The level of convention over configuration

Eg. In [Ruby-on-Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) you do not do a lot of configuration or boilerplate code. Instead, the framework forces you to follow a number of naming conventions. If you follow the rules a lot of stuff "just works" auto-magically. [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) (Java) on the other hand requires a lot of XML configuration and you have to build a lot more of the scaffolding.

2) The purity of the "templates"

Eg. In [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com) ([Python](http://python.org/)), you use a template language to define the views. In [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) the out-of-the-box views are HTML with lots of code mixed in.

3) The level of modularity

Eg. I had to say out-of-the-box in the previous answer as in vanilla ASP.NET MVC you can use either the Web Forms or the [Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ASP.NET_Razor_view_engine) "view engines" but many more are available (including the [Django template system](http://ndjango.org/index.php?title=NDjango_Home)). Frameworks like Spring and [Monorail](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/) also offer many "view engines" while other frameworks typically only offer one way to do it.

4) Full platform vs simple MVC framework

Eg. Some frameworks go beyond the MVC to provide more out-of-the-box functionality and deep integration into other layers. For example, Rails and Django provide a standard ORM (data access). Both Spring and Monorail provide both an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and an [IOC container](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). Django even provides an automatically generated administration interface for your model. In contrast, ASP.NET MVC leaves stuff like IoC and ORM (even whether to use them at all) up to the developer.

5) Language dependance

Eg. If you choose Django, you are choosing Python and choosing Rails means choosing [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/). However, Spring can potentially be used with any language that runs on the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). There is also [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/) which is Spring on the .NET platform. ASP.NET was designed to work equally well with C# and VB.NET but can be used from any .NET language. Different languages have different strengths and weaknesses that extend beyond the MVC framework.

So what is better? Well, with a framework like Rails you can get up and running very quickly but can run into problems when you try to colour outside the lines. Spring offers a full "enterprise" platform which some might find too much. ASP.NET MVC offers a nice web layer but leaves most of the application plumbing up to you. Which is better depends a lot on your personality and what you are trying to do.

I mentioned a few frameworks above but there are of course many, [many more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). As it happens, I typically use ASP.NET MVC on [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) myself.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is first and foremost an Architectural Design Pattern. ASP.NETMVC/Ruby on rails/Strut and other MVC Frameworks are basically implementations of this pattern.

There's a good write-up about MVC as a design Pattern at MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx

And an old article but one of the best at tech republic

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/mvc-design-pattern-brings-about-better-organization-and-code-reuse/1049862